# F# SQL provider deal with secrets

Tags: f#

In an F# script, I am able to query a Postgres dB without problem:

```ml
#r "nuget: SQLProvider"
#r "nuget: Npgsql, 6.0.9"

open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql

[<Literal>]
let dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL

let homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)

let [<Literal>] connString = "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=SomeDb;Username=USER_NAME;Password=PASSWORD"

[<Literal>]
let resPath = "C:/Users/320136294/.nuget/packages/npgsql/6.0.9"

[<Literal>]
let indivAmount = 1000

[<Literal>]
let useOptTypes = Common.NullableColumnType.OPTION

[<Literal>]
let owner = "public, admin, references"

// create a type alias with the connection string and database vendor settings
type sql =
  SqlDataProvider<
      dbVendor,
      connString,
      "",         //ConnectionNameString can be left empty
      resPath,
      indivAmount,
      useOptTypes,
      owner>

let ctx = sql.GetDataContext(connString)
```

However, the fact that `connStr` is a `Literal`, means that I cannot do this:

```ml
let userName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")
let [<Literal>] connString = $"Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=SomeDb;Username={userName};Password=PASSWORD"
```

[image]

What can I do in order to create the connection string but not expose my password in the code? The point is that I don't want to have the situation whereby the password ends up in source control.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this library: https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.Data.LiteralProviders

e.g.

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open FSharp.Data.LiteralProviders

type Sql = SqlProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
                   Env.CONNECTION_STRING.Value>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#r "nuget: SQLProvider"
#r "nuget: Npgsql, 6.0.9"

open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql

[<Literal>]
let dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL

let homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)

let [<Literal>] connString = "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=SomeDb;Username=USER_NAME;Password=PASSWORD"

[<Literal>]
let resPath = "C:/Users/320136294/.nuget/packages/npgsql/6.0.9"

[<Literal>]
let indivAmount = 1000

[<Literal>]
let useOptTypes = Common.NullableColumnType.OPTION

[<Literal>]
let owner = "public, admin, references"

// create a type alias with the connection string and database vendor settings
type sql =
  SqlDataProvider<
      dbVendor,
      connString,
      "",         //ConnectionNameString can be left empty
      resPath,
      indivAmount,
      useOptTypes,
      owner>

let ctx = sql.GetDataContext(connString)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**